# how to transform YYMMDDHH timestamp in date python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following timestamps

```
 import pandas as pd
        import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts':[14102100, 14102101, 14102102]})
```

And they are in format `YYMMDDHH`.

How can I transform them into a readable date ?

I tried `pd.to_datetime(df.ts, format="YYMMDDHH")` but it doesnt work

Comment: Do you particularly need to use pandas? The standard datetime module offers the function strptime() for exactly this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need formats with `%` by http://strftime.org/:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts':[14102100, 14102101, 14102102]})

print (pd.to_datetime(df.ts, format="%y%m%d%H"))
0   2014-10-21 00:00:00
1   2014-10-21 01:00:00
2   2014-10-21 02:00:00
Name: ts, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```